# Understanding the flow of try-catch-finally

Tags: javascript

Is this flow sematically correct:

```js
try{
 somePromise().then().finally()
}catch(err){
 doSomethingWithError()
}
```

Generally, we see either try-->catch--> finally, or somePromise().then().catch().finally()

The code is working fine, what I wanted to know, whether the finally() will attach itself to the somePromise() flow , for will it go with the try{} block

Comment: yes its legal although you are using promises so it won't do what you think.

Comment: 1) Run the code 2) See what happens. Spoiler: you get a SyntaxError. So it's not even syntactically valid, let alone semantically correct.

Comment: @LionelRowe : I've run the code, and it works fine. The reason why I'm second guessing is, I want to know how finally works here. Will it attach itself to the somePromise(), or will it attach itself to try-block.

Comment: @Lakshya Without changing your code, I've edited your post to make it runnable. Result: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try"`

Comment: @LionelRowe, I just the saw `.catch` mistake that i did. Anyways my question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

u can expact the finally to happen after the catch which wont...
a better way in my eye would be like so (i also noticed a dot that is wrong in your syntax):

```
try{
   somePromise().then()
}
catch(err){
 doSomethingWithError()
} finally{
     // your finasllu code after all the process is done
}
```